# 就く in sports jargon

Tags: verbs, expressions

I know that 就く{つく｝means “to be hired”. But does it have a separate meaning in sports jargon (soccer, baseball...)

I’m referring to the following sentence:

全員、守備に就くため走った。

Comment: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%AE%88%E5%82%99%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F

Comment: Ah so it’s not only for sports ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> know that 就{つ}くmeans “to be hired”.

While that is not incorrect, I would rather suggest that you remember the meaning as "to assume a position".  Why?  Because while 「就く」 is in the active-voice form, "to be hired" is in the passive voice.

The 「就く」 in the sentence:

> 「全員{ぜんいん}、守備{しゅび}に就{つ}くため走{はし}った。」

is not all that different in that it means:

> "Everyone ran to assume a defensive position."

Sports or business, you are assuming/taking a certain position.  That is what 「～～に就く」 means.